# Send email using Spring and AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I don't have a clue what to do. I have searched a lot of tutorials and guides but none of it are working.  I don't know why but I think they are outdated, which makes things so complicated.

I have a Maven project that uses AngularJS and Spring. I wish to use Gmail as my sender. Based on my research I have to do something like this in my AngularJS Controller after using `ng-click`

```
$scope.sendEmail = function(){
        $scope.emailData.to = "to@gmail.com";
        $scope.emailData.subject = "Forgot Password";
        $scope.emailData.body = "Description here"

        EmailService.sendEmail($scope.emailData).then(function (response) {
            if(response.status=200){
                //sweetalert here
            }
        });


    }
```

and my `EmailService` is

```
angular.module('EmailService', []).factory('EmailService', ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        sendEmail: function (email) {
            return $http.post("/email/", email).then(function successCallback(response) {

                return response;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                return response;
                //error
            })
        },

    }
}])
```

I have a Controller in my Java that looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email")
public class EmailController {

    @Autowired
    EmailServiceImpl emailService;

    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Email sendEmail(@RequestBody Email email) {
        return emailService.create(email);
    }
 }
```

and `Email.java` contains

```
    private String toAddress;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
```

with getters and setters, my `EmailServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service("emailService")
public class EmailServiceImpl {

    public Email create(Email email) {

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("password");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");


        return email;
    }
}
```

so what's next?

Note: I'm using `JPA` and I'm using the `1.5.6.RELEASE` version.

Comment: You can use the interface JavaMailSender from Spring, here you can learn how to use it: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Comment: Any guide how to use it with angular?

Comment: This is a guide for consume RESTFul service with AngularJS: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/
If you are new using AngularJS and you want to learn more, check this course from coursera: https://www.coursera.org/learn/single-page-web-apps-with-angularjs

Comment: BTW you don't have a real question, check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited post. what's next to my code?

Comment: You need to give us more details about what's not working for you.  Have you seen the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ)?  It has answers to questions you haven't asked yet, as well as debugging tips.

Comment: @USS: please do not add italics or other formatting to words just because they are proper nouns. Java, Spring, Maven, Angular, just need the appropriate capital. There are not easier to read if they are emboldened.